# User migration (under 50) from Citrix workspace to office 365 and SharePoint

Tags: validation, migration, office365, citrix

Hi all asking for best applications and advice for migrating users from Citrix workspace to office 365 and SharePoint. Is it fairly straight forward or will I need external applications?

I’m not to sure with leaving Citrix as it doesn’t seem as straightforward as google workspace.